# Кодировка (кракозябры вместо русского языка)

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, как исправить данную проблему - вместо русского языка непонятные символы. Ошибка в кодировке, но как исправить не пойму.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
   body {
    background-image: url(bg.jpg)
   }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <br>
 <br>
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('games'); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM Games"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<p><center><font size=15 face='fantasy' color='#850909'> TopGames <center></font></p>";
echo "<table background='bgtable.jpg'>";
echo "<tr>
<td><center>Сортировка:<center></td>
<td><a href='price_up.php'>По возрастанию цены</a></td>
<td><a href='price_down.php'> По убыванию цены</a></td>
<td><a href='rating.php'> По рейтингу</a></td>
<td><a href='date.php'> По дате релиза</a></td>
</tr>";
echo "</table>";

echo "<table background='table.jpg'>";  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Genre'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Release_date'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Platform'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Rating'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>
</tr>";
} 
echo "</table>";  
mysql_close(); 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После строчки mysql_connect:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);
```

В head добавить:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Добавил, не помогло... какие еще варианты?
Сейчас код в кратце выглядит так:

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);
mysql_select_db('games');

Comment: upd. Не стал париться, перевел все в английский